# shell script to get raid controler details

Tags: raid5

How can I get the RAID 5 controller array details using a shell script command?

Comment: What controller? Name the maker and model and you may get an answer.

Comment: More importantly, on what operating system? Is this software RAID, hardware RAID, or do you want to handle both cases?

Answer (score 1):

LSI MegaRAID help is http://www.freebsdwiki.net/index.php/Megarc here.

3Ware tw_cli is well documented at http://www.lsi.com/DistributionSystem/User/AssetMgr.aspx?asset=55377 . The man page can be found online at for example http://www.cyberciti.biz/files/tw_cli.8.html

Adaptec is `arcconf getconfig 1`

If you have something else, `lspci` and `lspci -n` outputs please.

Answer (score 0):

See: [How to find RAID configuration/level and RPM speed having only remote access to the server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/211925/how-to-find-raid-configuration-level-and-rpm-speed-having-only-remote-access-to-t/211939#211939)