# Linux Centos Disk information on HP DL 160

Tags: linux, centos, hard-drive, hp-proliant

I have a HP DL 160 and I would like to know all possible information on my physical disks.
I want to know how many physical disks I have.
I want to know if they are in raid 1 or raid 5 etc.
I want to know if I can add disk or I have a disk that I can add to the operating system and use it.
I'm not sure which commands or utilities can show me these info
when I do df -h I get:

df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                      898G  4.5G  847G   1% /
/dev/sda1              99M   24M   70M  26% /boot
tmpfs                 2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm

Answer (score 2):

```
hpacucli
> controller all show config detail
```

That is the ultimate way to obtain disk and hardware raid information on an HP system.

Comment: Assuming the drivers are installed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of things you can inspect to learn about the disks installed in your system:

- `cat /proc/mdstat`: this file tells you all about the RAID devices you have configured, what type they are (RAID 0, 1, 5, etc.), and what physical disk partitions they're made of.
- `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id`: this directory lists all the disks your system knows about, and you can generally derive their model numbers from the filenames.
- `pvdisplay`: since your example indicates you're using LVM, `pvdisplay` will show you many of the attributes of the physical volumes that make up the logical volume.
- `lspci` will tell you about the disk controllers you have installed; they'll usually be named something like "IDE interface".

If you give some more specific information about what you're trying to accomplish, it'll be easier for people to post answers that are better related to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If the RAID setup has been done in the HP BIOS then I think it's possible to at their configuration through the IPMI tools. You could have 2 x disks in a mirror setup but linux would only see 1 disk as the RAID setup is in the bios.

The tools in `sg_utils` might also be helpful sg_scan will show what disks are visible:

```
sg_scan
/dev/sg0: scsi2 channel=0 id=0 lun=0 [em]
/dev/sg1: scsi3 channel=0 id=0 lun=0 [em]
```

sg_inq will then show more detail about a device:

```
$ sudo sg_inq /dev/sg0
standard INQUIRY:
  PQual=0  Device_type=0  RMB=0  version=0x05  [SPC-3]
  [AERC=0]  [TrmTsk=0]  NormACA=0  HiSUP=0  Resp_data_format=2
  SCCS=0  ACC=0  TPGS=0  3PC=0  Protect=0  BQue=0
  EncServ=0  MultiP=0  [MChngr=0]  [ACKREQQ=0]  Addr16=0
  [RelAdr=0]  WBus16=0  Sync=0  Linked=0  [TranDis=0]  CmdQue=0
  [SPI: Clocking=0x0  QAS=0  IUS=0]
    length=96 (0x60)   Peripheral device type: disk
 Vendor identification: ATA     
 Product identification: SAMSUNG HD161GJ 
 Product revision level: 1AC0
 Unit serial number:       S1VCJ9AZ302995
```

Answer (score 0):

You should reference the server specs and take a look at:

[How to find RAID configuration/level and RPM speed having only remote access to the server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/211925/how-to-find-raid-configuration-level-and-rpm-speed-having-only-remote-access-to-t/211939#211939)

You should provide the specific server model in the question. `dmidecode -t1` will give you that.

Assuming your system is a DL160 G6, the model usually comes with 4 drive bays that accommodate 3.5" disks. 

See the HP Quickspecs at: http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13247_na/13247_na.html

In some rare configurations, you can have 8 disks on a DL160 model. Do you not have physical access to the system?

Answer (score 0):

Have look at https://github.com/pturmel/lsdrv

This script will show you what drives you have and what are they connected to. I should give you pretty much everything apart of hardware RAID configuration.