# vSphere 4.0 - Hardware system Monitoring

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp, vmware-vsphere, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have an ML350 G6 with ESXi 4.1 Free (vSphere Hypervisor 4.1 Free version) installed. Since ESXi is a bare-metal hypervisor install I was not able to install the HP Proliant Support Tools for Windows.

What is not clear to me is how I can make vSphere to notify me when a hardware component fails. For example one of the disks in the RAID1 config fails or a memory module is generating some errors etc. Do I need to install something extra inside ESXi? And where do I configure an email address to notify me?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Kind Regards,

Gert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install the [HP ESXi offline bundle for ESXi 4.1](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=3884315&prodNameId=3884316&swEnvOID=4091&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-1a452a67d79b40db8c4cee372a) to expose HP-specific monitoring information. You still won't get proactive (email) alerts, but you will be able to check health status via the vSphere client. In the future, install the [special HP build of ESXi](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/servers/software/vmware/index.html) which has these agents preinstalled.

Also see: [How to find out more hardware details using only ESXi4.1 and (possibly) shell](https://serverfault.com/questions/313843/how-to-find-out-more-hardware-details-using-only-esxi4-1-and-possibly-shell/313884#313884)

Comment: We use the regular non-HP-specific ESXi and you still get lots of good health info as it comes.

Comment: You don't get Smart Array disk information unless you use the HP build. Not an issue in shared storage or large ESXi deployments. It's more of an issue in the OP's case, since it's direct-attached storage.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll try the offline bundle and see where that gets me.

Answer (score 1):

HP Systems Insight Manager (SIM) can discover and given the right credentials access the CIM-provided system health information on that server, although if you'd used HP's own version of ESXi that comes with additional health information providers but the default ones will be fine I'd imagine. I'm no expert on running with just the free version of ESXi but I don't think it comes with any way of alerting you about this itself out of the box, although if you had the paid version and vCenter they certainly can do that.